# How to generate a new unsigned APK file after already having generated one?

Tags: android, apk

I already generated an unsigned APK file for my project last month, and, now when I want to generate a new APK file based on my existing progress, it still shows the same version. How can I build and generate a new APK file altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating new apk by changing `versionCode` and `versionName` to updated one. My previous version code was 1 and version name was 1, I have changes it like:

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
```